# Multiple conditions look up

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, vlookup

I am having trouble building a spreadsheet, the problem its my data table. I want to be able to pull data from the table, something that will match data from column A, **and** column B (on the same row) and give me the value in C.

Something like a double VLOOKUP matching two inputs (cells) to the table and giving me the third with the data I want.

Comment: changed the sheet permissions. will try the formuala given.

Comment: edited the formuala to  "=query('Fleet Log'! C:E;"select 'Fleet Log'!E where 'Fleet Log'!C=C2 and 'Fleet Log'!D=B42")" still not working, im prob doing something rong still, i have a value error, also, does it matter that im trying to pull the data from another sheet?

Comment: This question would be more valuable if you could add some sample data and what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this:

```
=query(A:C;"select C where A=x and B=y")
```

with `x` and `y` replaced by what it is you wish to select.

Since sight of your spreadsheet, I am not sure of what you would like where but suggest:

1. insert a column immediately to the right of D in Fleet Log and in E2 enter:
   `=C2&"|"&D2` and copy down to suit.
2. in Sheet5 Cell C3:

   `=iferror(vlookup(C$2&"|"&B3,'Fleet Log'!E:F,2,0),"")`

and copy down to suit.

I suspect =VLOOKUP will not work 'backwards' (ie to its left) but INDEX/MATCH may suit. Keep the formula from 1. above but put it in G2 instead (without inserting a column). Then in Sheet5 Cell C3 copied down to suit:

```
=iferror(Index('Fleet Log'!$E:$E,match(C$2&"|"&$B3,'Fleet Log'!$G:$G,0),""))
```

I'm getting curious to know whether this will work/suit!

Comment: is there anyway i can have this using the column "g" for the =C2&"|"&D2, as columns c to f must remain in that order due to the copy/pasting input of the data? and thanks for the help, has helped alot.

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks a bunch for the help ^^

Comment: just saying thanks again, since due to your help i was able to finish my project ^^